# Bookshelf/Bookshelf-modelbase problems adding functions and accessing base in extend

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to learn Bookshelf.js. I'm using [*bookshelf-modelbase*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-modelbase) to help with models, and I'm using [*password-hash-and-salt*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-hash-and-salt) to help with storing passwords in the database.

At the moment I'm trying to add a function to set a user's password, using *password-hash-and-salt* to generate a string that is stored in the `password` column of the database.

I've got my model declared like this (in *db.js*):

```
var knex = ...;
var bookshelf = require("bookshelf")(knex);
var ModelBase = require("bookshelf-modelbase")(bookshelf);
var Joi = require("joi");
var password = require("password-hash-and-salt");

module.exports.User = ModelBase.extend({
    tableName: "users",
    hasTimestamps: false,
    validate: {
        username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(64).required(),
    },
    setPassword: function (pw, callback) {
        var user = this;
        password(pw).hash(function (err, hash) {
            if (err)
                callback(err);
            else {
                console.log(user); // debugging
                user.update({password:hash}).then(function (updated) {
                    return callback(null);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And I'm attemptingn to use it like this:

```
var db = require("./db.js");

db.User.findOne({username:"somebody"}).then(function (user) {
    user.setPassword("password", function (err) {
        if (err) 
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log("value set", user.get("password"));
    });
});
```

I'm having problems on the `user.update(...)` line:

```
TypeError: user.update is not a function
```

Now, *bookshelf-modelbase* adds an `update()` function to the model, but I guess I'm just not sure how to use it.

My original attempt used `this.update()` but I discovered that `this` is something different inside `password(pw).hash`'s callback, which is why I did `var user = this` first.

When I log `user` to the console up in that callback (where the "debugging" comment is) I do see a user model bug as the error message described, there's no `update` function:

```
constructor {
  attributes: 
   { username: 'somebody',
     id: 1,
     password: '' },
  _previousAttributes: 
   { username: 'somebody',
     id: 1,
     password: '' },
  changed: {},
  relations: {},
  cid: 'c1',
  validate: 
   { isJoi: true,
     _type: 'object',
     _settings: null,
     _valids: { _set: [] },
     _invalids: { _set: [] },
     _tests: [],
     _refs: [],
     _flags: {},
     _description: null,
     _unit: null,
     _notes: [],
     _tags: [],
     _examples: [],
     _meta: [],
     _inner: 
      { children: [Object],
        renames: [],
        dependencies: [],
        patterns: [] } },
  _events: { saving: [Function: validateSave] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _knex: null,
  id: 1 }
```

I'm... not really sure how to do this, I'm kind of in the dark.

How do I properly add this `setPassword` function to my `User` model, call it, and do an update from within it? All I really found was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114865/bookshelf-js-function-inside-extend) and, while the title is promising, it doesn't *seem* to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's actually a pretty simple mistake.

Looking at the [code for *bookshelf-modelbase*](https://github.com/bsiddiqui/bookshelf-modelbase/blob/master/lib/index.js), `update` is a class method, not an instance method (it's passed as the 2nd parameter to Bookshelf's `extend`) (also, obvious reading the modelbase docs in retrospect).

So it can't be used in that context. The most straightforward thing is to just use the instance method `save` instead.

So, switching `user.update` to `user.save` solved the problem.